# Next Results/Page 2 just repeats same results of search results pagination script

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I have a search results with pagination page that works only for the first results page 1. When a user enters a search keyword that has 11 results they go to search.php and see the results correctly:

« ‹ Page 1 of 2 pages, displaying 1-8 of 11 results › »

However, when the user clicks on the > to go to page 2, the URL changes correctly to search/2/?search_text=query  but I get the same

« ‹ Page 1 of 2 pages, displaying 1-8 of 11 results › »

and the same first 8 results instead of the last 3 results as expected

This is the URL I see when I click the next arrow for page 2:
http://example.com/search/2/?search_text=usertext

Here is the full code:

```
$search = $_GET['search_text'];   

try {

// Find out how many items are in the table
$total = $dbh->query("
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
stories
WHERE
stories.category = \"$search\"
")
->fetchColumn();

// How many items to list per page
$limit = 8;

// How many pages will there be
$pages = ceil($total / $limit);

// What page are we currently on?
$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
array(
'options' => array(
    'default'   => 1,
    'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

// Calculate the offset for the query
$offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;

// Some information to display to the user
$start = $offset + 1;
$end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

// The "back" link
$prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=1" title="First page">&laquo;</a>   
<a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;</a>' : 
'<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;
</span>';

 // The "forward" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) .
'&search_text=' . $search . '" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="
?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : '<span
class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';

// Display the paging information
echo '<div id="paging"><p>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ', $pages, '
pages, displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', $total, ' results ',
$nextlink, ' </p></div>';



 // Prepare the paged query
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        stories
    WHERE
        (stories.category = :input)
    ORDER BY
        SID
    LIMIT
        :limit
    OFFSET
        :offset
');

// Bind the query params
$stmt->bindParam(':input', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();


// Do we have any results?
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // Define how we want to fetch the results
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);

    // Display the results
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you click on one of your page links, you lose the POST data.

So `$search = $_POST['search_text'];` would not work. Unless you have a reason not to, I don't see why you can't use use `$_GET` instead, and then put `search_text` into your links. For example,

```
'<a href="?page=1&search_text=' . $search . '" title="First page">&laquo;</a>'
```

And don't forget to change your form to use method GET.

I'd look into the php function `http_build_query` to help create the link incase the user inputs quotation marks.

Comment: Oops, I used search_term instead of your search_text.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a single quote before &search_text

Comment: If you print out $offset before the second query, is it -8?

Comment: Doesn't that mean $page has a value of 0? Since $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit = (0 - 1) * 8 = -8. So maybe your first query returned an empty result or there is something wrong with the filter_input()

Comment: OK. Got the search results page to work using GET method and no errors. There are 11 results as there should be, limited to 8 per page. But, when I click the next button and go to page 2, it just gives me the same 8 results instead of the last 3 results. So I'm back at square one despite switching to GET method